# ultimate aliases for git fails (__git_aliases command seem to be deprecated)

Tags: bash, git, zsh

Im trying to create git aliases with autocomplete using [The Ultimate Git Alias Setup](https://gist.github.com/mwhite/6887990). I did everything in the instructions, but putting the following in my .zshrc file results in an error:

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion                                                                                                                                                                
fi


function_exists() {
    declare -f -F $1 > /dev/null
    return $?
}

for al in `__git_aliases`; do
    alias g$al="git $al"

    complete_func=_git_$(__git_aliased_command $al)
    function_exists $complete_fnc && __git_complete g$al $complete_func
done
```

The error is not intuitive: `.zshrc:153: parse error near`\n'`

but trying to run `__git_aliases` in the command line gives: `zsh: command not found: __git_aliases` so i figured that was the problem.

I then found online that this might been deprecated from git and that this line is supposed to give the same out put:

`git config --global alias.aliases "config --get-regex 'alias*'"`,

but that didnt work.

I also tried

`git config --list | grep -oP '(?<=alias\.)\w+'`

with no success.

EDIT:

Trying this command:

`(git config -l | grep '^alias\.' | cut -d'=' -f1 | cut -d'.' -f2)`

gave me the list of aliases but only the aliase name. 
I still get the same error so im guessing there are 2 things to sort out here, one related to the git aliases list and one related to zsh.

Comment: to use the same shorthand within the git config, I found I had to escape the `\.`. Eg. `list-aliases = config --get-regexp '^alias\\.'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hit the same problem when cygwin updated to git 2.21.0; this fixed it for me:

```
for al in $(git config --get-regexp '^alias\.' | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | cut -f 2 -d '.'); do

  alias g${al}="git ${al}"

  complete_func=_git_$(__git_aliased_command ${al})
  function_exists ${complete_fnc} && __git_complete g${al} ${complete_func}
done
unset al
```

Answer (score 2):

A more robust and clear solution seems to be to replace use of

```
__git_aliases
```

with

```
git --list-cmds=alias
```